# Why not working Ajax AutoCompleteExtender?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

As far as I research from the Internet,I wrote an AutoCompleteExtender to pull the data from a WebService.I can't find what is wrong.
I have to use .Net 4.0 and StoredProcedure. I want to search that start with the word `'al'` in a single table, but I can't find those,Certainly,without the case-sensitive.

HTML Code;

```
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="txtArama_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" DelimiterCharacters=""
                        Enabled="True" ServiceMethod="EtiketAutoComplete" ServicePath="~/AutoComplete.asmx"
                        TargetControlID="txtArama" MinimumPrefixLength="2">
                    </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

WebService Code;

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()]

public class AutoComplete : WebService
{
[WebMethod]
public string[] GetEtiket(string prefixText)
{
    try
    {
        DataSet ds;
        ArrayList PN = new ArrayList();
        DBProvider DBProvider_ = new DBProvider();
        DBProvider_.AddParameters("@Etiket", SqlDbType.NVarChar, prefixText);
        ds = DBProvider_.ExecuteDataSet("EtiketAutoComplete", CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        if (ds != null)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                PN.Add(dr["Etiket"]);
            }
        }
        return (string[])(PN.ToArray(typeof(string)));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your service method should : "GetEtiket" not "EtiketAutoComplete". Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Your webservice method name is `GetEtiket` but why you put this `ServiceMethod="EtiketAutoComplete"` ?